# What can be said among the lost on Mars that alters one's mood?

Tags: creative-writing, dialogue

Mars has had around a dozen outposts in that time. What interesting thing can **change** the mood of a group of lost travelers on Mars?

It can be said in general or with a few lines of story build up.

Example
Hey guys, imagine yourself making it through this and being lost in your hometown without a Google Map.

Comment: I feel like this either needs additional context to make sense, or you're looking for something clever to be said (which would be asking what to write). I THINK you're looking for a funny or inspirational speech about the situation, which would require context AND be asking what to write. Please clarify.

Comment: Yeh funny one line @DWKraus thanks for printing this out, I minimized the context to get close abstract answers tide to survival.

Comment: Voted to close because this question is "asking what to write" without context, character, theme, or intent. The questions/answers here need to be useful to the larger writing community, not just a prompt to generate pithy jokes for you.... I suggest focusing on **character dynamics**: *who says this, and what does it reveal about that character*, not 'Ho-humm, time for another interchangeable cast member to say a generic Joss Whedon anachronistic (instantly-dated) cultural-reference for the audience."

Comment: Hi @wetcircuit Yes, I agree, once Himanshu-Jain answered and got votes, I didn't want to delete what you suggested. Delete it and update it later, or let it be closed and ask to reopen it. I fear being hammered with downvots. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No words can be **interesting** in a grave situation like then, where people are lost on Mars and not even sure if they would ever be able to find their way back home again and even uncertain about their survival - except for something which can give them a ray of hope, show some light at the end of the tunnel. Not sure about your storyline, but you will have to think on these lines to lift up their moods.

The details about if those outposts can communicate with themselves or earth are also missing. Maybe something where one of the outposts could find a way to repair their communication equipment, and it's possible that soon they could be able to contact earth.